# uitextview delete text button touchhold to repeat

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uitextview, ios5.1, backspace

I have a uitextview that is editable.I am trying to add a backspace delete button that mimics the standard keyboard backspace/delete button operation.ie touchhold to repeat function.

Comment: OK. What have you tried? What is your question? What do you need help with? Are you implying that you are using your own custom inputView? The best way to get good answers is to ask a good, complete, clear question.

Comment: u touchhold the standard key board delete key and it repeats.I need a button that mimics this action.I've looked into NSTimers.A example of this would be appreciated.Or is there just something simple I'm missing.

Comment: Using timers is the approach I would use. Start a repeating timer when the user presses the button. Cancel the timer when the user releases the button. Each timer action should delete/backspace.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by adding a button on screen without adding a target. Then I would use touch events to trigger the button action. When you create the button, set the tag to a unique value. In my example I set the tag to 100. Then implement the following code and you should be good to go.

```
- (void)backspace {
    if (![textField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSString *backspace = textField.text;
        int lengthofstring = backspace.length;
        backspace = [backspace substringToIndex:lengthofstring - 1];
        textField.text = backspace;
    }
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches  withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if (touch.view.tag == 100) {
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(backspace) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches  withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if (touch.view.tag == 100) {
        if (timer != nil)
            [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches  withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if (touch.view.tag == 100) {
        if (timer != nil) {
            [timer invalidate];
            timer = nil;
        }
    }
}
```